# Finding free and open (alternative) dataset for Tour Recommender System and Running SPARQL Query on it's endpoint

Tags: sparql

I am new on web of data and linked open data. I have a problem by finding open dataset for a Tour Recommender System. I found a dataset here [Tour-Pedia](http://tour-pedia.org/about/lod.html) and it has a SPARQL sample query as well. But I don't know how to fetch data by using that query or another one. Please help me to get out of this problem.

Finally I can ask you to give me a free link for Tour information available on Web of Data (connected to DBpedia), and a sample query to find out places or reviews about those places.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem here? Send the query to the endpoint with the URL http://tour-pedia.org/sparql as stated in the description. that'S all you have to do

Comment: Okay, I tried a lot but the endpoint for this sparql engine on tour-pedia is not working. Did you query that??

Comment: Then you should ask the maintainers.